# How can I delete a record from a custom grid / table using the REST API?

Tags: acumatica

I don't see any examples in the Acumatica help or in the training on how to actually remove / delete a record from a custom screen / table using the REST (Contract-based) API.  How would one go about doing this?  Is it a PUT with different syntax? I did see a Stack Overflow case on deleting detail records - I tried this method and it didn't work for me.

[Acumatica REST API - Delete SalesOrderDetail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834460/acumatica-rest-api-delete-salesorderdetail)

That also refers to a header/detail setup, which I don't have (only grid details). Any help would be appreciated.   Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply send a DELETE request with the id or the key of your record. That will result in the deletion of the specified record.

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'https://ACUMATICA_URL/entity/Default/20.200.001/ShippingBox/d9ec53fa-b454-4cf0-b398-817b3b1a84aa'

curl --location --request DELETE 
'http://<Base endpoint URL>/entity/Default/20.200.001/ShippingBox/TEST'
```

You can find more information at the following links:

[Remove a Record by Key Fields](https://help.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=d806636f-3cb8-4fd6-bc1e-fef9cdf9683d)

[Remove a Record by ID](https://help.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=04825ddc-c3af-49de-8663-ae119e84b987)

Comment: I continually get this error:  "No entity satisfies the condition."  I know the key field values are correct.

Comment: @pmfith have you tried to send the request using the id instead of the key fields? Does it work that way? You have already extended the endpoint, correct?

Comment: yeah - I figured it out that I can retrieve by key fields to get the id, then delete using the id.  Still can't delete just using the keyfields, but oh well...     Thanks Samvel ;D

Comment: @pmfith that's strange that your keys work for the get request but fail for the delete request. Are you using the same format there? :D